# How to find longest substring given a string?

Tags: string

Input:string

Output:longest substring

Constraints:

- total lenght of substring must be less than 50
- ignore all the white spaces
- List item
- If a word contains "," or "." count them too.

  eq. "string." lenght is 7

Can you show me how can I implement this ?

Comment: So you want this in [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))?

Comment: What programming language?  What does the code around it look like?  What have you tried so far?  There's not much to go on here.

Comment: @crashmstr No I just need the algorithm for now to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In **C#** you can use `string.Split` and `OrderByDescending`:

```
var longest = "your string here"
    .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(s => s.Length < 50)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```